# Can I mongodump from within my app?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My client wants to be able to dump the DB and also import, if need be, from within the app. Is this possible?

Thanks.

[EDIT]
I need to execute this in javascript. The client wants to be able to click a button in the app  to export the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this

If your app is running (locally on port 3000, add 1 to the port) it will dump to a directory called `dump` in your current working directory.

```
mongodump --port 3001
```

You can also restore the same way, from within the dump directory of the database you're looking to restore (usually meteor)

```
mongorestore --port 3001 --db meteor ./meteor
```

Keep in mind to use these tools you need `mongodump` and `mongorestore` installed. On mac you can install them with [homebrew](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) (mac) or [aptitude](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) (ubuntu)

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make this clear, but I wanted to execute this in javascript, so that the user could dump by just clicking a button. Thanks.

Comment: @NateDavidRivera You could use a package like this one, https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongodump-s3, to dump it to s3, from which you could download it from. The underlying step is essentially the same as above, except the dump is uploaded to s3

Comment: How would you execute `mongodump --port 3001` in javascript? Having it dumped locally is perfectly fine in my situation and the dump should be very small in size.

Comment: That package would execute it for you server side. It looks like the use 'exec' to do it (see https://github.com/SamDuvall/mongodump-s3/blob/master/lib/dump.js). And it looks like they zip it too which is surprising, it looks a bit good for a use to me too!